# Passing variable to be used with urlopen()

Tags: python-3.x, urlopen

I am trying to find out how to pass the variable to `urlopen()`.

In my first code project I have a user entering a URL into an input box and then have it passed to a variable.

Input box:

```
eBox = Entry(root, textvariable=url)
```

Passing input to variable:

```
url=StringVar()
```

I then have a define for URL:

```
def addy():
    text = url.get()
    if not url.get():
        msg = messagebox.showwarning( "Project", "You must enter a URL!")
```

My exection code:

```
def execute():
    execute = urllib.request.urlopen()  #how do I use the variable within the ()?
```

The issue I am trying to resolve being a new coder is how I can have, `execute = urllib.request.urlopen()` to use the variable now holding the user input so it executes that URL.

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: You've already figured out how to get the entered URL, you just need to pass it.

Comment: I figured out how to pass the entry to a variable which was no issue. Thew issue  had was using the variable in the urlopen() line.

I have now figured it out and I have tested it to make sure it is using the input from the user variable.  It is working properly now.

I appreciate the input....